# Sphinx - Use ellipses (…) in code-block snippets

Tags: python-sphinx

Consider you document a long code snippet and you want to represent repetitive values and lines in it with ellipses … (`&hellip;`) and vertical ellipses ⋮ (`&vellip;`).

Here's an example record in JSON.  There are 26 kids and you don't want to show all of them.

```
.. code-block:: json

   {
       "total": 26,
       "kids" [
           {
               "_id":  1,
               "name": "Alice",
               "age":  3
           },
           {
               "_id":  2,
               "name": "Becky",
               "age":  3
           },
           ...,
           {
               "_id":  26,
               "name": "Zoe",
               "age":  4
           }
       ]
   }
```

Human readers can still see this as a JSON snippet/code, generalize and guess the pattern between *"Becky"* and *"Zoe"* represented by the ellipsis (...).

But Sphinx returns the error because this snippet has an invalid syntax.

```
$ make html
...
/.../docs/source/sample.rst:3: WARNING: Could not lex literal_block as "json". Highlighting skipped.
```

Can I use ellipses in code-block (with syntax highlighting)?  Please note the example doesn't have to be in JSON.  You will see this issue in other languages such as Python too.

Comment: Try the `:force:` option (https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#directive:option-code-block-force).

Comment: If `:foce:` does not work, there are less appealing options. Unfortunately, JSON does not support comments. For languages that do support comments but treat ellipses as a syntax error, I comment out the ellipses. If you don't mind dirtying up your JSON data, you could insert a data element `{"MOAR_KIDS": 999},` and surround it with a lot of whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the option `:force:` and add custom CSS to disable the error highlighting:

```
.highlight .err {
    border: inherit;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

[image: Rendering result]

Comment: Dedication: This answer is based on mzjn and Steve Piercy.